# Visual studio XAML IDE Vertical tag visualisation

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, ide

Im just wondering what you use to get the vertical visualisation lines between XAML open and close tags, it makes the XMALso much easier to read.

I cant find a better place to ask this but im sure there might be, sorry if its broken the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the Visual Studio extension called "Indent Guides": https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e792686d-542b-474a-8c55-630980e72c30 ?

It puts little guides in your VS2013 (and perhaps 2012) that show indents in the XAML editor. If you didn't mean that, I'd still recommend a look as it makes things a lot easier to read!